# Why does this method write a file in the same directory and not in the one specified?

Tags: python

There are images in E:/images/projects/1/extracts. extracts has a subdirectory called cropped. When I run the code bmp files are generated in the extracts folder not in the cropped subfolder. I am running under Windows.

```
from PIL import Image
import os.path, sys

path = "E:/images/projects/1/extracts"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

def crop():
    for item in dirs:
        fullpath = os.path.join(path,item)         #corrected
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
            im = Image.open(fullpath)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
            w, h = im.size
            imCrop = im.crop((0, 30, w, h-90))
            imCrop.save(os.path.join(path,"cropped",f + '.bmp'), "BMP", quality=100)

crop()
```

Comment: because you are using `path` instead of `fullpath`  when you save the image

Comment: path = "E:/images/projects/1/extracts" why should I use fullpath? Further testing has shown os.path.join(path,"cropped",f + '.bmp') = "E:/images/projects/1/extracts\\cropped\\filename.bmp". that should be ok.

Comment: Then if it should be ok your question doesn't need an answer

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki "it should be ok" = "it should work" but it doesn't

Comment: Debug line by line, check that the folder you are saving is the desired one. are the values of `f` and `e` what they are supposed to be when you do `f, e = os.path.splitext(fullpath)`?  Are you debugging your code line by line and checking at each step that the values are the expected ones right? At what line do you have a discrepancy and what is this discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

Trouble was that

```
f, e = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
```

included a an absolute path in the variable f

The variable "path" also had an absolute path. When the following executed

```
os.path.join(path,"cropped",f + 'Cropped.bmp')
```

it ignored the first absolute path including the "cropped" subdirectory

The solution was to use split(..) on the f variable

```
dirName, stemName = os.path.split(f)
imCrop.save(os.path.join(dirName,"cropped",stemName + 'cropped.bmp'), "BMP", quality=100)
```